# Preventing re-rendering of entire component in React Native when state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am new to React Native and I am trying to create a component that wraps a React node with a Tooltip using a list of steps. Everything works fine except that when I click "next," the entire page gets re-rendered, including the content in other tooltips. I tried to use useMemo but it didn't work.

Could someone please help me figure out the issue?

```js
export function Main({
    showProgress,
    allowChildInteraction,
    arrowHeight,
    arrowWidth,
    backgroundColor,
    childContentSpacing,
    closeOnChildInteraction,
    disabled,
    showSkipButton,
    nextButtonText,
    previousButtonText,
    skipButtonText,
    finishButtonText,
    onComplete,
    useAs,
    style,
    onSkip,
    content,
    listOfSteps
}: MainProps): ReactElement {
    const styles = mergeNativeStyles(defaultStyle, style);
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const [tooltipVisibility, setTooltipVisibility] = useState(
        listOfSteps.map(step => {
            return !disabled && step.order === 1;
        })
    );
    const tooltipRefs = Array.from(Array(listOfSteps.length), () => useRef());

    const isReactNativeElement = (element: any) => {
        return React.isValidElement(element) && typeof element.type === "function";
    };
    const containesChilds = (ele: any): boolean => {
        return ele.props && ele.props.content && ele.props.content.length > 0;
    };

    // const getPageName = (ele: any): string => {
    //     return ele?.props?.content[0]._owner.stateNode.props.navigation.state.params.title;
    // };
    const wrapInStepper = (key: string): boolean => {
        return listOfSteps.some((step: ListOfStepsType) => step.target === key);
    };
    const getStep = (key: string): ListOfStepsType => {
        return listOfSteps.filter((step: ListOfStepsType) => step.target === key)[0];
    };
    const next = (step: any) => {
        // const visibilites = tooltipVisibility.map((_: boolean, index: any) => {
        //     return index === step + 1;
        // });
        console.warn("next");
        setTooltipVisibility(visibilites => {
            const newVisiblity = visibilites.map((_: boolean, index: any) => {
                return index === step + 1;
            });
            return newVisiblity;
        });
    };
    const skip = () => {
        setTooltipVisibility(tooltipVisibility.map(_ => false));
        emitOnSkip();
    };
    const previous = (step: any) => {
        const visibilites = tooltipVisibility.map((_: Boolean, index: number) => {
            return index === step - 1;
        });
        setTooltipVisibility(visibilites);
    };
    const emitOnComplete = () => {
        if (onComplete?.canExecute) {
            onComplete?.execute();
        }
    };
    const emitOnSkip = () => {
        if (onSkip?.canExecute) {
            onSkip?.execute();
        }
    };
    // const getCircularReplacer = () => {
    //     const seen = new WeakSet();
    //     return (key: any, value: any) => {
    //         if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
    //             if (seen.has(value)) {
    //                 return;
    //             }
    //             seen.add(value);
    //         }
    //         return value;
    //     };
    // };
    const mapRecursive = (
        children: any,
        callback: any,
        tooltipRefs: any,
        visibility: any,
        next: any,
        previous: any,
        skip: any
    ) =>
        React.Children.map(children, (child: any): any => {
            const key = child.key.split(".")[3];
            if (React.isValidElement(child) && wrapInStepper(key)) {
                const step = getStep(key);
                return (
                    <Tooltip
                        isVisible={visibility[step.order - 1]}
                        arrowSize={{ width: arrowWidth, height: arrowHeight }}
                        backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
                        childContentSpacing={childContentSpacing}
                        closeOnChildInteraction={closeOnChildInteraction}
                        closeOnBackgroundInteraction={closeOnChildInteraction}
                        allowChildInteraction={allowChildInteraction}
                        closeOnContentInteraction={false}
                        disableShadow={false}
                        placement={step.placement}
                        onClose={() => {
                            console.warn({ closeOnChildInteraction });
                            if (!closeOnChildInteraction) {
                                setTooltipVisibility(tooltipVisibility.map(_ => false));
                            }
                        }}
                        contentStyle={{
                            minWidth: 250,
                            flex: 1,
                            height: "auto",
                            backgroundColor: "transprant"
                        }}
                        content={
                            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", position: "relative", padding: 10 }}>
                                {showProgress && (
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            position: "absolute",
                                            top: -5,
                                            left: -5,
                                            backgroundColor: "red",
                                            zIndex: 1000,
                                            borderRadius: 50,
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 30,
                                            justifyContent: "center",
                                            alignItems: "center"
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Text style={{ color: "white", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 12 }}>
                                            {step.order}/{listOfSteps.length}
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                )}
                                <Text style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 22 }}>{step.title}</Text>
                                <Text style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 17, marginTop: 5 }}>
                                    {step.description} {visibility[step.order - 1]}
                                </Text>
                                <View
                                    style={{
                                        display: "flex",
                                        flexDirection: "row",
                                        justifyContent: "flex-end",
                                        alignItems: "flex-end"
                                    }}
                                >
                                    {showSkipButton && step.order !== listOfSteps.length && (
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                            onPress={() => {
                                                skip();
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: "#000", marginRight: 10 }}>
                                                {skipButtonText.value}
                                            </Text>
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                    )}
                                    {step.order - 1 !== 0 && (
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                            onPress={() => {
                                                previous(step.order - 1);
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: "#000", marginRight: 10 }}>
                                                {previousButtonText.value}
                                            </Text>
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                    )}
                                    {step.order !== listOfSteps.length && (
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                            onPress={() => {
                                                Keyboard.dismiss();
                                                next(step.order - 1);
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: "#000" }}>{nextButtonText.value}</Text>
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                    )}
                                    {step.order === listOfSteps.length && (
                                        <TouchableHighlight
                                            onPress={() => {
                                                setTooltipVisibility(tooltipVisibility.map(_ => false));
                                                emitOnComplete();
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: "#000" }}>
                                                {finishButtonText.value}
                                            </Text>
                                        </TouchableHighlight>
                                    )}
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        }
                    >
                        {/* <View */}
                        {/* key={step.order - 1}
                            onLayout={event => {
                                const index = step.order - 1;
                                tooltipRefs[index] = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                            }} */}
                        {/* // > */}
                        {callback(child)}
                        {/* </View> */}
                    </Tooltip>
                );
            } else if (isReactNativeElement(child) && containesChilds(child)) {
                return React.cloneElement(child, {
                    content: mapRecursive(
                        child.props.content,
                        callback,
                        tooltipRefs,
                        tooltipVisibility,
                        next,
                        previous,
                        skip
                    ),
                    key: uuid.v4() as string
                });
            } else {
                return callback(child);
            }
        });
    if (useAs === "container") {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {mapRecursive(
                    content,
                    (ele: any) => {
                        return ele;
                    },
                    tooltipRefs,
                    tooltipVisibility,
                    next,
                    previous,
                    skip
                )}
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container} ref={ref}>
                {mapRecursive(
                    content,
                    (ele: any) => {
                        return ele;
                    },
                    tooltipRefs,
                    tooltipVisibility,
                    next,
                    previous,
                    skip
                )}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```